# Сортировка записей mysql по дате

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите по такому моменту: есть таблица с полем `varchar(12)`. В поле хранится дата вида `31.04.2015`

Как можно сортировать по возрастанию даты в этом поле?

Comment: Почему вы храните дату в поле varchar?

Comment: Действительно, если хранить дату как Date, то сортировка возможна средствами базы данных

Comment: спасибо за советы, но меня сейчас интересует как можно отсортировать по полю именно в таком виде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Внимание! Решение ниже это КОСТЫЛЬ, написанный по просьба автора вопроса. В общем случае нужно сменить тип поля на Date.

[Посмотреть пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3e29/1)

Вам правильно говорят, что вы сами создали себе проблему.
Вот еще одно решение стандартными средствами:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_test` ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') ASC;
```

---

```
`date` - ваше поле с датой.
```

Вот ссылка на [документацию](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) по функции STR_TO_DATE.

Answer (score 3):

Дату надо хранить в формате date. Это единственно возможный вариант.
Если по незнанию дата была введена в каком-то кривом формате, то переделать его в нормальный.

Бояться переделок не нужно.
Во-первых, это не так трудно, как кажется. Во-вторых, переделок будет МНОГО, и надо сразц к этому привыкать.

А вот чего надо бояться - это костылей и говнокода.

Answer (score 0):

Эх, любим мы сначала создать проблему... Ну, как-то так, например:

```
SELECT CAST
(
  CONCAT
  (
    SUBSTRING(mydate,7),
    SUBSTRING(mydate,3,4),
    SUBSTRING(mydate,1,2)
  ) 
  AS DATE
) 
AS `d` FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `d`
```